# How to change session variable to a specific variable in a loop

Tags: php, html

I have a while loop that sorts out every course(or product or anything) i have in the database, in everyone that it sort out there is a button created with it and it's role to take you to the details page of that course..

so I've created a session with the course_id and stored it in it then i tried to change this session['course_id'] to the id of each course the button is displayed next too

```
$query = "SELECT *  FROM courses ";
$runquery= mysqli_query($conn , $query);
if($runquery){
    while($rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($runquery)){
            echo $rows['course_name'];
            echo "<center>  <form method='POST' action='courses.php'> <input type='submit' name='button' value='More Details'> </form></center>";
            if(isset($_POST['button'])){
                $_SESSION['course_id'] = $rows['course_id'];
            }
    }
}
echo $_SESSION['course_id'];
```

I expect when I press on the first button to see the course_id = 1 and the second =2 etc..
but in the future it will be randomized so whatever shows up first should have it's own id not just 1,2,3,...

Comment: i know that i am not explaining well but it's like a search engine and i want to link every search appears to it's actual link

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code that it's really hard to help you. It simply doesn't work that way. Why are you using sessions to do that task at all? Do you know what sessions are? Try reading some tutorials on how to use `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: I know all of these functions.. but I am creating a search engine for a very limited database.. if you could help how can i even implement it.. and get the buttons to locate me to the course's details page
i thought about using sessions to take the product_id and then redirect me to the main course page which will check the ID and based on it will load the courses information.. i am not creating a page for each course...

Comment: I answered by basic example without sessions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for a submitted course id first, before displaying your list of courses. I would assume you want to display specific information for the selected course, and you're storing the course id in the session so you can redirect to another page to do that.

```
if (isset($_POST['course_id'])) {
    $_SESSION['course_id'] = $_POST['course_id'];
    // redirect to the course page
}
```

Now, you don't need a bunch of different forms. You can use buttons instead of inputs and put all the courses in the same form. If you use the course id as the value of the button, the value of the clicked button will be the value you get in `$_POST` when you submit the form.

```
$runquery = mysqli_query($conn , "SELECT * FROM courses");
if ($runquery) {
    echo '<form action="courses.php" method="post">';
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runquery)){
        echo $rows['course_name'];
        echo "<button type='submit' name='course_id' value='$rows[course_id]'>More Details</button>";
    }
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Comment: This is actually quite simple and it's working very well.. it's either my brain is dead from countinious work or you are smart and smooth with the codes.. or both :)) thx

Answer (score 1):

Just a basic example, please consider understanding how it works.

---

You need 2 `php` files:

1. For example `index.php`
2. For example `info.php`

In first file you need to list the courses, something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM courses";
$runquery = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if($runquery){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runquery)){
      echo '<a href="info.php?course_id='.$row['course_id'].'">'.$row['course_name'].'</a><br />';
   }
}
```

In second file something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_id = ".(int)$_GET['course_id']; // <-- IMPORTANT! Cast it to int to prevent SQL injections.
$runquery = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if($runquery){
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runquery);
   print_r($row);
}
```

Try it.

Comment: this is working well with me and redirecting me with the value i want without using sessions like you said.. I could use it and try to redirect myself again through that other page.. but it's not how i want exactly.. I mean really thx but if i found no other solution i'll use yours for sure

Comment: @YoussefHossam this method does have some potential advantages. For example, if the course id is included in the URL you can bookmark courses, where that won't really work with the post/session approach.